# django: Usage logging tracker application

Tags: django

I am very new to web development. I have build a django application. Now what I want to do is log user behavior such as mouse clicking, time spend on certain section of the webpage. I am very new django so my django application is very simple and I want to start exploring how to build an user behavior tracker to my django application. Ideally I like to save all this session information in database/table. Where should I start and any example would be a great help.

Comment: Check this http://www.woopra.com/

Answer (score 2):

What you want is just web analyics. There are lots of ready made systems that can do this for you, so you won't need to make it yourself in Django.

I would recommend [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) as it's an open source solution. The drawback is that you have to install it yourself, so something like [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) might be easier to set up, just remember that using this option enables google to track your visitors too.

There are a lots more web analytics software. For a good overview check this Wiki page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_analytics_software

Comment: Thanks but I want to understand which section of the page they are referring to most, for example dom level inspection? etc.

Comment: Did you look into various analytics software features? I'm sure there's one solution that covers your requirement.